adding CAS authentication to my django rest framework API with django-cas-ng 404 error in accessing url
I'm trying to add CAS authentication to my Django Rest API with django-cas-ng. For the moment i just try to configure dajngo-cas-ng and understand how it work. When I try to access to this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/  (specify in this doc https://djangocas.dev/docs/latest/configuration.html#settings) I receive a 404 error.
This is my urls and part of my settings

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'back',
    'mail',
    'formulaire',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_cas_ng',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django_cas_ng.middleware.CASMiddleware',
]



AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'django_cas_ng.backends.CASBackend',

)


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}



CAS_SERVER_URL = 'https://...'
CAS_VERSION : 3
CAS_LOGOUT_URL_NAME = 'https://...'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('back.urls')),
    path('', include('formulaire.urls')),
    path('', include('mail.urls')),

    path('accounts/login/', cas_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='cas_ng_login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', cas_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='cas_ng_logout'),

]


404 error
I verify url and settings but it seems to have no problems, did I forget something ?
Thanks for your help
